# Rails 4:TypeError - no implicit conversion of String into Integer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file, ruby-on-rails-4, readfile

I am reading an empty HTML-File like this:

```
file = File.read("file_path/file.html", "wb")
```

Why does that throw this TypeError?

> no implicit conversion of String into Integer

**Log:**

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 8ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

TypeError (no implicit conversion of String into Integer):
  app/controllers/abc_controller.rb:49:in `read'
  app/controllers/abc_controller.rb:49:in `build'
```

Comment: show full exception log please

Comment: @sig added log entry

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the file is empty, what do you want to read exactly?

The second parameter for [File#read](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/IO.html#method-c-read) is optional, and should be the length of the String you want to read out of the file. `"wb"` isn't an Integer, hence the error messsage.

The parameters you used look more like [`open`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/File.html#method-c-open).

## Read a file

If you want to read the file, just use

```
content = File.read(filename)
```

## Write a file

If you want to write it, you can use

```
File.open(filename,'w+') do |file|
  file.puts "content"
end
```

`'w+'` is a file mode which :

> Overwrites the existing file if the file exists. If the file does not
>   exist, creates a new file for reading and writing.

## Existence of a file

If you want to check that a file exists :

```
File.exists?(filename)
```

## Is a file empty?

If you want to check that an existing file is empty :

```
File.size(filename)==0
```

The file could be full of whitespaces (size > 0, but still "empty"). With Rails :

```
File.read(filename).blank?
```

Comment: Is there a way to check if the file is empty or not?

Comment: With `w+`, the existing file will be overwritten. If the file doesn't exist, it is created. What do you want to do exactly?

Comment: I want to get the content of a file I created. But I don't know if that file is empty or not. If it is empty it throws an error. So I need to precheck whether that file is empty or not.

Comment: `file.size.zero?` perhaps.

Comment: That is what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For reading a file you can use rb instead of wb.

```
data = File.open("ur path","rb")
```

Comment: `data` isn't data in this case, it's a file object. Not its content.

Comment: @EricDuminil Yaa you are right data is file object you can iterate using data do |file|
  file.puts "content"
end